# Getting Cloud Functions url for unit testing with emulator

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a couple of Cloud Functions that interact with Cloud Firestore. I've managed to start emulator for both (`firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore`) and I run the request and it works. However, the URL for emulated functions is fairly long...

`http://localhost:5001/my-app/us-central1/myFunc`

I would like to either get a whole url or assemble it somehow. The `my-app` could be in theory read from `.firebaserc` where the default is specified. However, I am not sure about port or region.